# Flipping Pebble Screen Issue

Tags: c, pebble-sdk

I'm writing a Pebble Time Watch app using Pebble SDK 3.0 on the basalt platform that requires text to be displayed upsidedown.

The logic is:-

1. Write to screen
2. Capture screen buffer
3. Flip screen buffer (using flipHV routine, see below)
4. Release buffer.

After a fair amount of experimentation I've got it working after a fashion but the (black) text has what seems to be random vertical white lines through it (see image below) which I suspect is something to do with shifting bits.

[image: Upsidedown text]

The subroutine I'm using is:-

```
void flipHV(GBitmap *bitMap) {
  GRect fbb = gbitmap_get_bounds(bitMap);
  int Width = 72; // fbb.size.w;
  int Height = 84; // fbb.size.h;
  uint32_t *pBase = (uint32_t *)gbitmap_get_data(bitMap);
  uint32_t *pTopRemainingPixel = pBase;
  uint32_t *pBottomRemainingPixel = pBase + (Height * Width);

  while (pTopRemainingPixel < pBottomRemainingPixel) {
    uint32_t TopPixel = *pTopRemainingPixel;
    uint32_t BottomPixel = *pBottomRemainingPixel;
    TopPixel = (TopPixel << 16) | (TopPixel >> 16);
    *pBottomRemainingPixel = TopPixel;
    BottomPixel = (BottomPixel << 16) | (BottomPixel >> 16);
    *pTopRemainingPixel = BottomPixel;

    pTopRemainingPixel++;
    pBottomRemainingPixel--;
  }
}
```

and its purpose is to work though the screen buffer taking the first pixel and swapping with the last one, the second one and swapping it with the second last one etc etc.

Because each 32 bit 'byte' holds 2 pixels I also need to rotate it through 16 bits.

I suspect that that is where the problem lies.

Can someone have a look at my code and see if they can see what is going wrong and put me right.  I should say that I'm both a C and Pebble SDK newbie so please explain everything as if to a child!

Answer (score 2):

Your assignments like

```
TopPixel = (TopPixel << 16) | (TopPixel >> 16)
```

swap pixels pair-wise

```
+--+--+    +--+--+
|ab|cd| => |cd|ab|
+--+--+    +--+--+
```

What you want instead is a full swap:

```
+--+--+    +--+--+
|ab|cd| => |dc|ba|
+--+--+    +--+--+
```

That can be done with even more bit-fiddling, e.g

```
TopPixel = ((TopPixel << 24)               |  // move d from  0..7  to 24..31
           ((TopPixel <<  8) & 0x00ff0000) |  // move c from  8..15 to 16..23
           ((TopPixel >>  8) & 0x0000ff00) |  // move b from 16..23 to  8..15
           ((TopPixel >> 24)               |  // move a from 24..31 to  0..7
```

or - way more readable(!) - by using `GColor8` instead of `uint32_t` and a loop on a per-pixel-basis:

```
// only loop to half of the distance to avoid swapping twice
for (int16_t y = 0; y <= max_y / 2; y++) {
  for (int16_t x = 0; x <= max_x / 2; x++) {
    GColor8 *value_1 = gbitmap_get_bytes_per_row(bmp) * y + x;
    GColor8 *value_2 = gbitmap_get_bytes_per_row(bmp) * (max_y - y) + (max_x - x);
    // swapping the two pixel values, could be simplified with a SWAP(a,b) macro
    GColor8 tmp = *value_1;
    *value_1 = *value_2;
    *value_2 = tmp;
  }
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I haven't compiled this code. It might also be necessary to cast the `gbitmap_get_byes_per_row()...` expressions to `GColor8*`. And the whole pointer arithmetic can be tuned if you see that this is a performance bottle-neck.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try.

Comment: I've solved this by declaring everything as uint8_t.  The main problem, though, was the difference between the image width and the image width in bytes (which for anything other than GBitmapFormat8Bit) are not the same and required additional processing to take account of unused bytes. The answer can be found at http://forums.getpebble.com/discussion/27862/puzzling-gbitmap-get-data-behaviour#latest

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I needed to replace all of the uint32_t with uint8_t and do away with the shifting.